# SOAP web service, change namespace without editing code?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, soap, namespaces

Am I able to change the namespace in all SOAP web service methods, **without editing the code**?

This line...

```
<ConfirmIdentity xmlns="http://www.domain.com"> ?
```

is this possible?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <ConfirmIdentity xmlns="http://www.domain.com">
      <ConfirmIdentityRequest>
        <ApplicationCrediential>
          <API_Username>string</API_Username>
          <API_Password>string</API_Password>
        </ApplicationCrediential>
        <SessionId>string</SessionId>
      </ConfirmIdentityRequest>
    </ConfirmIdentity>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: in what language is the web service created?

Comment: it is in C# , but I can't edit the code :(

Comment: why not make your own that consumes that one?

Comment: I guess could do that, if thats the only way to do it - just a little more time consuming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge you cannot change the namespace, it is set in the context of the class and method.  Even if you somehow wrapped this from another, it would still override.  You're only option is a proxy consumer.